# Content field not recognized on Page Layout

Tags: content-type, site-column, page-layout, content

I'm using SharePoint Designer 2010 to create a custom page layout.

I have a content type called "Web Part Page" and its parent is "Page" content type. I have several site columns associated with this content type. One of the fields is a RichImageField that I want to use as the page banner. I added site column labeled "PageTopImage" and I added the field to the content type's site column lists.

However, when I add that field to the Page Layout Mark up, it can't be recognized. When I edit the page in the browser I don't get the sharepoint image upload tool. It just leaves an empty space/div.

Here's the markup I used to add the image field. Basically I drag/Drop using SP Designer Tool Box:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
 <WebPartPages:spproxywebpartmanager runat="server" id="ProxyWebPartManager">
 </WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager>  
 <!--banner section -->
 <div id="banner_wrapp_inner">
   <div id="banner_inner">                  
     <PublishingWebControls:RichImageField FieldName="782a3849-f4b0-4c29-835d-072b5d487291" runat="server" id="RichImageField1">
     </PublishingWebControls:RichImageField>
   </div>
 </div>    
</asp:content>
```

Also tried markup like this:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField FieldName="PageTopImage" runat="server">
</PublishingWebControls:RichImageField>
```

But the result is the same. The weird thing, I have another RichImageField associated with the content type and it shows normally. It's just the new column that it's not working.

Please help find out the reason behind this behavior.

I appreciate your assistance.

Thanks

Ahmed